# How to force Firefox to use HTTP/3 (QUIC) only?

Tags: firefox, http3

I know browsers usually use HTTP/1.1 to start a connection, discover the capability of the server and upgrade the connection to more advanced protocol.

Is there a way to bypass the discovery and start every connection with HTTP/3? I know it most likely won't work for every site, but I just want to experiment with it and see how it goes.

The solution I found online only says how to enable HTTP/3 support. I want to force browser to use only HTTP/3. If FireFox can't do that, I can switch to Chrome if it can. (I know how to do it with cURL, but I want to experience it from a browser)

Comment: Forget every site, it wont work with most sites.  Ive not played with it, but ehat happens if you block tcp on port 80 and 443? Also, you may want to specify your OS.

Comment: If I block TCP 80/443, it will simply fail. It won't try UDP 443.